# Python tkinter I can't get a scrollbar to work

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I can't get a scrollbar to work.  Can somebody take a look at my code and tell me what I've done wrong?

```
import tkinter as T
from tkinter import ttk

fldrs = ['C:\\Program Files\\Telegram\\Downloads',
        'C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows Defender Advanced Threat Protection\\Downloads', 'C:\\Users\\All Users\\Microsoft\\Windows Defender Advanced Threat Protection\\Downloads',
        'C:\\Users\\Default\\Downloads', 'C:\\Users\\MaLonn\\Downloads',
        'C:\\Users\\Public\\Downloads']
top = T.Tk()
frm1 = ttk.Frame(top, relief='ridge', borderwidth=2)
frm1.grid()
scrb = ttk.Scrollbar(frm1, orient=T.HORIZONTAL)
txt1 = T.Text(frm1, xscrollcommand=scrb.set)
for f in fldrs:
    txt1.insert(T.END, f)
txt1.grid()
scrb.config(command=txt1.xview)
scrb.grid()
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This code does not run on it's own, so it's hard to fix.

Comment: Example updated.

Comment: You haven't turned word wrapping off.

Comment: That did it.  Thanks, @Bryan Oakley.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scrollbar won't work because by default the text widget wraps the text. Therefore, there cannot be any text beyond the right margin.

If you want to use a horizontal scrollbar, you need to turn word-wrapping off.

```
txt1 = T.Text(frm1, xscrollcommand=scrb.set, wrap="none")
```

Comment: Yes, Bryan Oakley.  You solved this for me back in May.  Working the SO magic, I see.  I marked it as the correct answer.