# Python tkinter scrollbar does not have a channel to scroll. Can only scrol via arrow

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Like the title says.  Code:

```
root = tk.Tk()
frm2 = ttk.Frame(root, relief='ridge', borderwidth=2)
frm2.grid(row=1)
scrb = ttk.Scrollbar(frm2, orient=T.HORIZONTAL)
txt1 = T.Text(frm2, width=30, wrap=T.NONE, xscrollcommand=scrb.set)
for f in fldrs:
    txt1.insert(T.END, f + '\n')
    i += 1
txt1.grid()
scrb.config(command=txt1.xview)
scrb.grid(row=i + 1, column=0)
```

I've done some searching, but I seem to finds things using a canvas as an example.  And I found a good tut from here, but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Is it the same question as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67765917/python-tkinter-i-cant-get-a-scrollbar-to-work)?

Comment: No.  With that question, I couldn't get a scrollbar.  With this question, I can get a scrollbar, just it doesn't work right.  There's no channel to scroll.  The only way to scroll is to click the arrows on the right and left of the bar.

Comment: The scrollbar is working actually.  Try adding `sticky="ew"` to `scrb.grid(...)`.

Comment: That did it!  Thank you, @acw1668.